# Line items repeating themselves in crystal report

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal reports and cant find how to correctly list my line items. My report will run with no problems but my line items repeat themselves multiple times. For example instead of having four different line items for each row in expenseDtls they repeat themselves across multiple pages.  If I move the fields on the report to the header I only get one row instead of four. I also have select distinct records checked in the options. Here is my query. Any help would be appreciate!

```
    private void launchReport(int pKReport)
    {
        using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var query = (from s in db.expenseHdrs
                        join d in db.expenseDtls on s.rptNo equals d.rptNo
                        where s.rptNo == pKReport
                        from g in db.employees
                        join r in db.expenseHdrs on g.pk equals r.empPk
                        select new { s.period, s.description, s.department, s.rptNo,            
                        s.reimbursement, g.name, d.expDate, d.expType, d.expDesc});

            CrystalReport1 cr1 = new CrystalReport1();
            cr1.SetDataSource(query);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Most likely the problem is not with the code that invokes CR, it is with the report. Run the report interactively and see what you get.

Comment: What do you mean run it interactively?

Comment: Found the fix on the site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525651/crystal-reports-data-repeating-if-chart-is-included